# AES encryption in VB .net output doesn't match website

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

I am trying to implement AES encryption on an embedded platform with matching version in VB .net. The embedded platform has hardware AES acceleration and gives me the same result as http://testprotect.com/appendix/AEScalc. I have searched around and am using the following VB .net code to try to do the same but get different results.

```
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

    Dim key() As Byte = New Byte() {&HDE, &HAD, &HBE, &HEF, &HA5, &HF4, &H56, &H12, &HDE, &HAD, &HBA, &HAB, &H1, &H92, &H83, &H74}

    AES.Key = key
    AES.KeySize = 128
    AES.BlockSize = 128
    AES.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
    AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
    Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor

    Dim input() As Byte = New Byte() {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H9A, &HBC, &HDE, &HF0, &H24, &H68, &HAC, &HE0, &H78, &H94, &H56, &H12}

    Dim enc() As Byte = DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length)
```

My inputs are:
key: 0xdeadbeefa5f45612deadbaab01928374
input: 0x123456789ABCDEF02468ACE078945612

Output given by website and embedded platform:
0x2b9481a0f7b32f1088407d8834c3dc4c

Output given by VB .net:
0x49ca99ee420a82acd72f1532141385fd

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the VB .net? Thanks.

Comment: An update on this. I've noticed that every time I run the VB I get a different answer. I don't change anything just build and run repeatedly. I have also tried using System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged and cryptostream stuff rather than transform but also get wrong (and different each time) results

Comment: Finally solved thanks to @vcsjones. It turns out that writing KeySize clears the previously written Key.

Answer (score 0):

try this function , hope this helps

**Encrypting**

```
Public Function AESEncryption(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
      Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
      Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
      Dim encrypted As String = ""
      Try
          Dim hash(31) As Byte
          Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
          Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
          Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
          AES.Key = hash
          AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
          Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
          Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
          encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
          Return encrypted
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
  End Function
```

**Decrypting**

```
  Public Function AESDecryption(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
      Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
      Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
      Dim decrypted As String = ""
      Try
          Dim hash(31) As Byte
          Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
          Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
          Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
          AES.Key = hash
          AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
          Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor
          Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(input)
          decrypted = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
          Return decrypted
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
  End Function
```

[Source](http://ultimateprogrammingtutorials.blogspot.com/2013/05/cryptographic-algorithms-for-vbnet.html)